# SQL - Consulta con jerarquías

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Tengo una duda de cómo consultar este tipo de estructuras en MySql. **Tablas:**

```
Usuario (idUsuario, dni, nombre, tipo); (el tipo puede ser Profesor o Alumno)
Profesor(idProfesor, materiaAcargo, *MAS ATRIBUTOS PARTICULARES*) el idProfesor es FK de idUsuario
Alumno(idAlumno, añoEnCurso, *MAS ATRIBUTOS PARTICULARES*) el idAlumno es FK de idUsuario.
```

Entonces si yo quiero realizar un JOIN entre Usuario y Profesor, hago lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT * FROM Usuario U, Profesor P WHERE U.idUsuario = P.idProfesor
```

Lo mismo entre Alumno y Usuario. Pero si ahora quiero traer todos los alumnos y todos los profesores con sus atributos particulares no sé como hacerlo.

**Ejemplo**

Usuario

```
0, 39098827, 0 //el tipo 0 representa alumno
1, 14582741, 1 //el tipo 1 representa profesor
```

Alumno

```
0, tercero_secundaria, ...
```

Profesor

```
1, matematica, ...
```

Resultado deseado

```
0, 39098827, 0, tercero_secundaria, ... NULL, ... //null serían los campos que corresponden a Profesor
1, 14582741, 1, NULL, ..., matematica, ... //null corresponde a los campos que son de Alumno particularmente
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

**Estructura Real**

No la había puesto, ya que pensé que tenía cosas de más que no ayudarían a resolver el problema, perdón por eso.

```
user(iduser, name, company, service, dni, photourl, role) //iduser es PK,
alert(idalert, iduser, serverTime, type) //idalert es PK, iduser es FK de user.iduser
alert_with_location(idalert, latitude, longitude, lastKnownLocationTime) //idalert es PK y es FK de alert.idalert
alert_checkout_missed(idalert, checkInTime) //idalert es PK y es FK de alert.idalert
```

Esas son las tablas reales. Necesito consultar todas las alertas en un intervalo de tiempo dado (utilizando el campo serverTime), pero quiero traer por cada alerta su información particular. De cada alerta quiero obtener la información que se encuentra en la tabla alert_with_location o alert_checkout_missed

Comment: pon la estructura de las tablas completa, no solo una parte

Comment: @shadow editado. Gracias por leer la pregunta, espero que sirva la información agregada!

Comment: Se puede hacer con left join, seleccionas todo de la tabla Usuarios y haces left join a las otras dos tablas con la FK. Para que no duplique registros en el resultado, en el where añades como condición que tenga bien un id_alumno>0 o un id_profesor>0, de modo que también obtengas resultados en el caso de que un usuario pueda tener ambos roles.

Comment: Gracias @Carmen, sos una grosa. Funciona increible! si quieres hacer una respuesta para que pueda votarte. Mil gracias!

Comment: Para eso estamos @FrancoBerardi, ahora te hago una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener todos los resultados, se seleccionan todos los usuarios y se hacen left joins a las otras tablas utilizando la foreign key. Para evitar los duplicados en el resultados, se añade como condición que esté en una de las otras tablas.

```
SELECT * FROM Usuario U
LEFT JOIN Profesor P ON U.idUsuario = P.idProfesor
LEFT JOIN Alumno A ON U.idUsuario = A.idAlumno
WHERE P.idProfesor>0 OR A.idAlumno>0
```

Comment: Carmen, creo que tienes que modificar el WHERE por >= sino el id 0 te lo pierdes

Comment: @FrancoBerardi por regla general no se suele usar 0 como identificador, por ejemplo en campos tipo autoincrement el primer registro es el 1, por eso no lo contemplé.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración :) saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolverlo fácilmente utilizando [OUTER JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-optimization.html) , por ejemplo LEFT JOIN.

Te quedaría algo similar a esto:

```
select * 
from usuario u left join alumno a
on u.idUsuario=a.idAlumno and u.tipo=0
left join profesor p
on u.idUsuario=p.idProfesor and u.tipo=1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbfd9c/10/0

Comment: Diego muchas gracias por responder y resolverme el problema. Tu respuesta fue igual de útil que la de Carmen, pero seleccione a ella como Mejor Respuesta, ya que me ha respondido antes. Te agradezco por tu ayuda!